# Vue Single File Component with Laravel 5.5

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.5

Issue:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

`Test.vue`:

```
<template>
    <p>test</p>
</template>

<script>
    //also tried export default
    module.exports = {
        name: "test"
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

`app.js`:

```
Vue.component('test', require('./components/Test'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    ...
});
```

And my usage inside `blade` template:

```
<test></test>
```

What's wrong?

I have some other components which work without errors. They were made ~half year ago, probably `npm update` messed things up, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to import component and add it like this :

```
import Test from './components/Test';

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        Test
    },
    ...
});
```

Youre problem seems to be related to this : [Components registration](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html)